# Failed to search for cards in react framework

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, search

I am creating a search engine in a web page that uses react, with the Searchcard.js file I try to filter the data using a ternary operation

```
const res = !search ? data : data.filter((dato) => dato.toString().toLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase()))
```

What this does is that when  **search** *(which is a state for the search input)* this void shows me all the **cards** *(that is, without any filter)*, but if this **search** has a **string** value then it searches or rather filtered the data according to **the value in search**. The first operation is done well, when there is nothing in search it shows all the cards, **the problem is that when I write something in search for some unknown reason it does not show me any data and the res instead of getting the data as an array does not it shows nothing, just an empty array (I see this thanks to console.log()).**

I also try with...

```
const res = !search ? data : data.filter((dato) => dato.name.toString().toLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase()))
```

What the console.log file shows when it is run and given a value to **search** in the **search input**

The first **console.log** file is to show what the search input captures, then it shows us a **console.log(data)** file that shows us the data from the **API**, **console.log(res)** finally we see an array that is supposed to that must store the data of the cards chosen by filtering but apparently it is **empty**

[console.log of the datas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubWXp.png)

I would appreciate it if you could help me find the error of this problem. I will leave the *Searchcard.js* codes, *the code of how to get the data* and *how the cards are created*.

**Searchcard.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'
import {Cards} from '../cards/Cards'
import { UseFetch } from '../UseFetch'

export const Searchcard = () => {
    //hooks
    const [url, setUrl] = useState("https://aves.ninjas.cl/api/birds") 
    const estado = UseFetch(url) /*Devuelve el objeto que tiene UseFetch (cargando, data) */
    const {cargando, data} = estado /*obtener los datos del objeto que entrego UseFetch */
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("")
    
    //Funcion que nos ayuda a capturar los valores dados por el usuario
    const searcher = (e) => {
        setSearch(e.target.value)
        console.log(e.target)
    }
    //Filtramos los datos
        const res = !search ? data : data.filter((dato) => dato.name.toString().toLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase()))
    
  return (
    <div>
        <input value={search} onChange={searcher} type="text" placeholder='¡Busca un pajaro!' className='form-control'></input>
    
    {
          cargando 
          ?
          <h1>Cargando...</h1>
           :
           <div>
            <Cards data={res} />    
            {console.log(data)}  
            {console.log(res)}
          </div>
  }
    
    </div>
  )
}

export default Searchcard
```

The data is pulled from a public API.

In order to extract data, I used

**UseFetch.js**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
export const UseFetch = (url) => {
  const [resultado, setResultado] = useState({ cargando: true, dato: null })
  useEffect( ()=>{
    getData(url)
  },[url])
  async function getData(url) {
    try{
      setResultado({cargando: true, data:null})
      const respues = await fetch(url)       
      const data = await respues.json()       
      setResultado({ cargando: false, data })
    }
    catch(e){
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
  return resultado
}
```

**cards.js**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {Cardsbird} from './Cardsbird'
import './Cards.css'
import Paginacion from '../Pagination/Pagination'



export const Cards = ({data}) => {
  const [actPag, setactPag] = useState(1)
  const [cardXpag] = useState(20)

  

  //
  const indUltimo = actPag * cardXpag;
  const indPrimero = indUltimo - cardXpag;
  const actCard = data.slice(indPrimero, indUltimo); 
  
  //Cambiar pagina
  const paginate = numPag => setactPag(numPag);

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      
        <ul className='cards'>
            {      actCard.map(p=>(
                  <li className='card-item' key={p.uid}>
                      <Cardsbird url={p._links.self}/>
                  </li>  
                ))
            }
            <div className='container2'><Paginacion cardXpag={cardXpag} totalCards={data.length} paginate={paginate}/></div>
        </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Cards
```

**cardsbird.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { UseFetch } from '../UseFetch'
import Modal from './Modal'


export const Cardsbird = ({url}) => {
    const estado = UseFetch(url)
    const {cargando, data} = estado 



  return (
    <div>
        {
            cargando
            ?
            <h1>Cargando...</h1> :
            <div className='card' style={{width:'14rem'}} data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target={`#id${data.sort}`}>
                <div className='card-header'>
                    <h5 className='card-title'>{data.name.spanish}</h5>
                </div>
                <div className='card-body'>
                    <img src={data.images.main} alt={data.uid} />
                </div>
                <Modal id={`id${data.sort}`} titulo={data.name.spanish} imagen={data.images.main} audio={data.audio.file} descripcion={data.iucn.description} habitat={data.habitat} tamaño={data.size} mapa={data.map.image} />           
            </div>
        }
    </div>
  )
}

export default Cardsbird
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was my stupidity, because I didn't see **how the name of the card is called inside the API**.

Was calling the name this way

```
const res = !search ? data : data.filter((dato) => dato.toString().toLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase()))
```

And it should be like this

```
const res = !search ? data : data.filter((dato) => dato.name.spanish.toString().toLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase()))
```